# Random forest (Rborist) with large dataset in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I am using `Rborist` to construct random forest in `R`. But, after building the model using training set, while using `predict` (`predict.Rborist`) function, R is crashing with the message "R for Windows GUI front-end has stopped working".

I am using a machine with 8 core CPU, 32 gb RAM and my data set has 150k records along with 2k variables. Building a random forest using the whole dataset requires 2 hours approx with parallel processing enabled.

While this might be a memory error, CPU or Memory usage status isn't indicating that. Please help.

Comment: You can try reducing your training data. Exactly how large is your total data (test+train+validation sets)?

Comment: Recently I tried the same process with 150k records and 12 variables only and the model got built but while predicting, once again R stopped working.

Comment: Well if your data has size of 'n', you can keep your training data at sqrt(n) and still manage to make statistical sense out of your model. Ideally the model building is pain in the neck... for predicting you can always split your data in smaller data sets...

Answer (score 2):

Indranil,

This is likely not a memory problem.  The predict() method had an error in which the row count was implicitly assumed to be less than or equal to the original training row count.  The version on Github repairs this problem and appears to be stable.  A new CRAN version is overdue, and awaits several changes.